# Issue trying to re-render react parent component from child

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments

Trying to re-render parent component from child component callback . in the Payment button I call axios to update a state, then I need the parent to show this new updated state, so I try to set a "false" state to true, which I am hoping will trigger  a re-render.

Error:

```
Line 28:4:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
```

from parent

```
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

<h4>
                    Purchase 5 more post's : <PaymentButton name="more post" price={5} description="create more post"
                        object={
                { email: user.email, max_posts: user.max_posts + 5 }
                        }
                        success ={()=>setSuccess(true)}

                    />

                </h4>
```

from child

```
const PaymentButton = ({ name, price, description,object }) => {

    const handleToken = async (token, addresses) => {
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/payment/checkout', {
            token,
            product: { name, price, description }
        });

        const { status , resolved} = response.data;

        console.log('Response:', response);
        console.log('network_status :', resolved);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(object))


        if (status === 'succeeded' && resolved ==='approved_by_network') {
            toast('Success! Purchase Approved. ', { type: 'success' });
            return axios.put('http://localhost:3000/api/users/getuser', { ...object });
            object.success


        } else {
            toast('Something went wrong, contact site admin about this', { type: 'error' });
        }
    };
```

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you are trying to do, and post the errors you are getting?

Comment: I tried to clarify a little, sorry about that!

Comment: Ok I think I see what is going on. If the request succeeds, you want to call a `success` function that was passed down from the parent, which will update the parent's state and trigger a re-render of the parent component.

Comment: I think problem #1 is that the `success` function is not in the `object` right now. It looks like you are passing `success` as a separate prop to the child, so you need to add it to the list `const PaymentButton = ({ name, price, description, object, success })`, and then call `success()` in place of your `object.success` line down there.

Comment: That line where you pass `{() => setSuccess(true)}` into the child component, is actually handing the child a function to call. So you need to make sure you are actually calling the function that the parent gave you, just as you would call any other function.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reverse **true** state by writing :

```
!success
```